# Get number by loop on if - PHP

Tags: php, math, numbers

I have this piece of code that loops 1 through 99 and is a formula.

```
function getExperienceByLevel ($maxLevel)
{
    $levels = array ();
    $current = 0;

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxLevel; $i++)
    {
        $levels[$i - 1] = floor ($current / 4);
        $current +=  floor($i+300*pow(2, ($i/9.75)));
    }

    return $levels;
}
```

First you initiate it like so `$aLevels = getExperienceByLevel(99);` then to see how much EXP you need to get to level `6` you do this `echo $aLevels[5];` since it's an array.

Now I'm trying to do reverse. Get Level by EXP.

```
function getLevelByExp($exp) 
{
    $aLevels = getExperienceByLevel(99);

    for ($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++)
    {
        if ($exp > $aLevels[$i-1]) 
        { 
            return $i;
        }
    }
}
```

So I try to do this:

```
$aLevels = getExperienceByLevel(99);
echo getLevelByExp(131);
```

When called upon `getLevelByExp(131);` or any number inside, it seems to return a `1` even though it should be `2` since Level 3 is `167` EXP and Level 2 is `80` EXP. Here's a reference image: http://i.imgur.com/gEYgu.png

Comment: have you checked the answer??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing two mistakes: You are indexing your levels array wrong. And you're checking it the wrong way. Use this:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/MGpOUu

```
function getExperienceByLevel($maxLevel) {
    $levels = array ();
    $current = 0;
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $maxLevel; $i++) {
        $levels[$i] = floor ($current / 4);
        $current +=  floor($i+300*pow(2, ($i/9.75)));
    }
    return $levels;
}

function getLevelByExp($exp)  {
    $levels = getExperienceByLevel(99);
    $current = 0;
    foreach($levels as $level => $required) {
        if($required>$exp)return $current;
        $current = $level;
    }
    return $current;
}

echo getLevelByExp(131);

// returns 2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function getLevelByExp($exp) {
    $aLevels = getExperienceByLevel(99);

   for ($i = 99; $i >= 1; $i--)
    {
       if ($exp > $aLevels[$i-1])
        {
        return $i;
        }
    }  
}
```

You are returning as soon as $exp > $aLevels[$i-1]. On the first runthrough of your original loop, $aLevels[$i-1] = $aLevels[0] = 0, so it will always return right away for any non-negative $exp value.

Answer (score 0):

You need the opposite conditional, and to compare to the next level, so you can determine that a given exp level does not fit into any higher level. This code works for me:

```
if ($exp < $aLevels[$i])
{ 
    return $i;
}
```

Nice and simple. Try it out: http://codepad.viper-7.com/FrjtHT

Answer (score 0):

change

```
if ($exp > $aLevels[$i-1])
```

to

```
if ($exp > $aLevels[$i-1] && $exp < $aLevels[$i])
```

checked and it is working

working example http://codepad.viper-7.com/BjmHad

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it like

```
function getLevelByExp($exp)      
{     
    $aLevels = getExperienceByLevel(99);     

    for ($i = 1; $i < count($aLevels); $i++) 
    { 
        if ($exp >= $aLevels[$i-1] && ($exp - $aLevels[$i-1] < $aLevels[$i] - $aLevels[$i-1]))  
        {  
            return $i; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Check out http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/paw-08f